# Change bold font

Tags: fonts, fontsize

I want to use **Avenir Next Medium** as the bold font for my document whenever I use `\textbf`. Is there a way I can use `\textbf` and specify a font to be used. After that, can I also customize the size for any font rendered using `\textbf`?

Comment: I assume you're using LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX?  If so it's not hard to do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the Avenir Next font is a commercial font, I'm assuming you are using either XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX.  It's easy to specify a different font for bold text. Here's a simple example:

```
% !TEX TS-program = XeLaTeX
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX,BoldFont={Linux Biolinum O},Scale=MatchLowercase]{Linux Libertine O}
\begin{document}

This is some text. \textbf{This is some ``bold'' text}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you use the LuaLaTeX format, you could achieve your objective by including the following instructions in the preamble of your document:

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[BoldFont = {Avenir Next Pro Medium},
             BoldItalicFont = {Avenir Next Pro Medium Italic}]
            {Avenir Next}
```

This setup obviously requires that fonts of the `Avenir Next Pro` family, distributed by Linotype, are available on your system.

If you use XeLaTeX instead of LuaLaTeX, you will probably have to use the actual file names of the fonts rather than "logical" font names such as "Avenir Next Pro Medium".

Comment: I had no (well, only a few) problems with XeLaTeX logical font names.